# Retrieve multiple key/values from query string with same parameter

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to extract multiple parameters from a query string, where the parameter has the same name, in my case `filter`. I can only seem to access the first instance of the filter using the following approach, and I also need to split the key/value out from the colon separator into an easier format to work with, which I'm not sure how best to approach. Grateful if anyone can point me in the right direction.

```
myURL =  example.com?someparam=test&filter=color:"GOLD"&filter=size:"10";

var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = urlParams,
    sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
    sParameterName,
    i;

for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
   sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

   if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
       return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : decodeURIComponent(sParameterName[1]);
   }
   }
  };

var filters = getUrlParameter('filter');

console.log(filter);
// Outputs...
color:"GOLD"
```

Comment: Have you looked at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let parts = myURL.split("&");
let filters = {};
parts.forEach(part => {
  if (part.includes("filter")) {
    let value = part.split("=")[1];
    let key = value.split(":")[0];
    filters[key] = value.split(":")[1];
   }
})
```

Output:

```
{
  color: "'GOLD'",
  size: "'10'"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to reinvent the wheel

There is already an excellent library for that: [query-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string)

```js
const query = require('query-string')

const url = 'someparam=test&filter=color:"GOLD"&filter=size:"10"';

const result = query.parse(url);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

`output`

```
{"filter":["color:\"GOLD\"","size:\"10\""],"someparam":"test"}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    myURL =  `example.com?someparam=test&filter=color:"GOLD"&filter=size:"10"`;

var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = myURL,
    sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
    sParameterName,
    i;

    return sURLVariables.filter(function(filters){
        return filters.includes(sParam);     
    }).map(function(filters){
        sParameterName = filters.split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] !== undefined && sParameterName[0] === sParam && sParameterName[1] !== undefined) {
            return  decodeURIComponent(sParameterName[1]);
        }        
    })
}



var filters = getUrlParameter('filter');

console.log(filters);
```