# Get the latest key param of multiple params from a single URL?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

When user is in page 'a' and there writes something in forms input field then goes from page a to page b and from there back to page a, here if user wants to get data from url, there could be two with the same name for example this is url `?name=james&name=alex`
my question is how to get that latest 'name' for example name `name=alex` is the new one. Here is how i get from url:

```js
const query = window.location.toString().split("?")[1];

const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(query);


const Name = urlParams.get("name") || props.order?.name;
```

```html
<Form.Item label={t( "orders.name")} name="name" initialValue={Name || ""}>
  <Input type="string" />
</Form.Item>
```

Comment: Each param should really have its own name, e.g. `name=james&name1=alex`, but you can use the same param name if you want. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64319356/retrieve-multiple-key-values-from-query-string-with-same-parameter

Comment: yes should, but when i come back to edit the same thing, i'm going to next page with history.push/ tried also history.replace still getting  two or three with same name

Comment: Why not use `localStorage`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: know how to add latest 'name' from url to localstorage

Answer (score 1):

This answer is adopted from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4297832/2096053).

You should instead encode your names as an array and set it to the name parameter. When you add a new name, use `Array.push(ITEM)` to add to the end, and to get the most recently added item use `Array[Array.length - 1]`.

```js
//URL to array:
function URLToArray(url, param) {
    return url.substring(url.indexOf(param + '=') + param.length + 1).split('&')[0].split('_');
}

//Array to URL:
function ArrayToURL(array, param) {
  return param + '=' + array.join('_');
}

/*************************************/

//You can then use this as such:

// Get Array
var myArray = URLToArray('https://google.com?name=Bob_Joe_Tom&state=Alaska_Texas_Main', 'name');

console.log(myArray);

// Get URL
myArray.push('Steph'); //Lets add a name to the array
var myNameUrl = 'www.google.com?' + ArrayToURL(myArray, 'name');


console.log(myNameUrl);
```

I have made this so you can have any number of arrays on the url as well, hence why I have the `state` value in the example, just to show it can discern between the two arrays.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you.

```js
function getLatestParamFromUrl(param="") {
  const url = new URL(window.location.href);

  const values = url.searchParams.getAll(param);

  const latestValues = values.length > 0 ? values.pop() : false;

  return !!latestValues && latestValues;
}

console.log(getLatestParamFromUrl("name"));
```

Comment: getting undefined

Comment: can you share the code what you are doing here ? or a snippet ?

Comment: the function here will return false if there is no param which present in the URL and if there then it will return you the latestone please check now.

Comment: i have updated the code this should work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230594/discussion-between-kunal-panchal-and-walee).